# How to view content of a file in CMD using Python?

Tags: python, windows, file, cmd, command

I want to view the content of a file areas.py in CMD. We use **cat** command to view the content on Linux. I want to know, which command works the same in CMD to view content using python.

Comment: type. This has _nothing_ to do with python

Comment: I have tried using type but still getting error :The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Are you sure you are in the correct directory?

Answer (score 1):

`type` command is the equivalent command of `cat` in Linux

[image: FYI]